# Faster version of strstr for fix string

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization, strstr, boyer-moore

I have a short string `s` (max 8 characters) which I want to search in many strings. Actually I want to search the first occurrence in each string of a stream. Finding the first index of `s` has to be as fast as possible for my use-case, because a massive amount of strings per second is processed and the latency is very critical. Of course, machines can be scaled, but a big point is to reduce costs (and latency).

In general I want to create a C (or C++) function which behaves like `strstr`, but for a fixed "needle". The needle is not known at compile-time, but only at runtime (at the startup).  However, it's okay to generate code at runtime and compile it (or any other "expensive" initialization is fine). Once the needle is known it won't change anymore.

Another detail: The needle will be in almost every string of the input stream. So it's okay if the algorithm is slower for the case that the needle is not available (because that will almost never happen). Also maybe important: The input strings have always extra 64 byte allocated at the end (which might be helpful for SIMD operations).

I was actually surprised that `strstr` is already quite fast, but I guess there might be a more optimal algorithm for the case that the needle is does not change?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Perhaps you could try some regex library. I'm not fluent enough in C++ to recommend one, but typically these libraries allow one to to "compile" a regex, building a "matcher object" that is optimized for that needle/regex, and then use that repeatedly on many haystacks/strings. This might be faster (or slower) than `strstr`.

Comment: The various algorithms implemented for `strstr` are indeed quite efficient, yet I agree there might be some improvements to derive from the repeated use of the same needle and also take advantage of the slack at the end of the string. Hence I vote to reopen this question.

Comment: Given the string length, I doubt that you can do much better than with the naive algorithm. SIMD optimization is indeed possible, by using bytewise comparison on whole vectors, then packing the bytes to bits with PMOVMSKB.

Comment: How fast can you read the string stream and does the needle ever span strings?  Yes, I am wondering if you can queue string collections to a thread pool:)

Comment: The limit is likely the memory bandwidth for fetching the haystack strings. Optimizing the compare code won't help beyond that.

Comment: See the [Boyer-Moore string-search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer–Moore_string-search_algorithm), which is “well-suited for applications in which the pattern is much shorter than the text or where it persists across multiple searches.” That web page shows a C implementation and notes it is part of the C++ 2017 standard library. However, with a maximum target string length of 8, I do not know if it will gain much over `strstr`.

Comment: If you already have an attempt (implementation) of what you envision, then this question (along with the code) could be posted on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  SO is more targeted toward helping people that have made an attempt at something, and run into a bug, or an unexpected behavior that they need help understanding and how to fix.

Comment: SSE4.2 has a bunch of funky string comparison instructions, e.g. _mm_cmpestra I've never used them, so can't say if or how they could help you with this.

Comment: Have you any actual reason to believe that such an optimization would beat the [existing optimizations of strstr](https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/string/strstr.c.html)?

Comment: strstr can't use SSE and be standard C. Other than that, no, because like I've said, I've never tried to use them.

Comment: Can you state a lower bound on what to expect as haystack length? What class of processor (as in number of cache levels) shall be assumed?

Comment: `extra 64 byte allocated` Don't see how this can be beneficial without either "permission to clobber" these (e.g. place a copy of needle), or information about content.

Comment: @greybeard: The extra 64 byte might contain rubbish. It's only needed to allow easier use of AVX in later steps of the pipeline. A lower-bound for haystack is maybe ~32 byte. However, for the case that the needle is not in the haystack, it might be shorter (but that's a rare case)

Comment: (@KevinMeier I forgot/overlooked *accessible without violation*.)

Comment: @SimonGoater Sorry, that question was meant for the OP. Note that using SSE for one specific optimization in an application that doesn't use SSE / FPU otherwise can make your application *slower* because now you've added the FPU registers to the context that needs to be saved / restored on each context switch...

Answer (score 1):

If your target handles unaligned reads gracefully, you could use this approach:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

char *mystrstr8(const char *s, uint64_t str8, uint64_t mask8) {
    for (const char *p = s; *p; p++) {
        const uint64_t *p64 = (const uint64_t *)(uintptr_t)p;
        if ((*p64 & mask8) == str8)
            return (char *)(uintptr_t)p;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

If the string is modifiable, has extra slack and its length is provided, you can remove the terminator test:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

char *mystrstr8_len(char *s, size_t len, uint64_t str8, uint64_t mask8) {
    char *end = s + len;
    uint64_t *e64 = (uint64_t *)(uintptr_t)end;
    uint64_t ee = *e64;
    *e64 = str8;
    for (const char *p = s;; p++) {
        const uint64_t *p64 = (const uint64_t *)(uintptr_t)p;
        if ((*p64 & mask8) == str8) {
            *e64 = ee;
            if (p < end)
                return (char *)(uintptr_t)p;
            else
                return NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

`str8` and `mask8` must be precomputed from the bytes of the needle string and according to the target endianness. For example, to search for `Hello` on a little endian machine `str8` is `0x6f6c6c6548` and `mask8` is `0xffffffffff`.

For short strings, this simplistic brute force approach might perform better than using a tailored Boyer Moore implementation, depending on your specific data: array and needle lengths and contents... You can start by comparing the performance with that of your standard library's `strstr` function.

Here is a benchmark for various string lengths:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

char *mystrstr8(const char *s, uint64_t str8, uint64_t mask8) {
    for (const char *p = s; *p; p++) {
        const uint64_t *p64 = (const uint64_t *)(uintptr_t)p;
        if ((*p64 & mask8) == str8)
            return (char *)(uintptr_t)p;
    }
    return NULL;
}

char *mystrstr8_8(const char *s, uint64_t str8) {
    for (const char *p = s; *p; p++) {
        const uint64_t *p64 = (const uint64_t *)(uintptr_t)p;
        if (*p64 == str8)
            return (char *)(uintptr_t)p;
    }
    return NULL;
}

char *mystrstr8_len(char *s, size_t len, uint64_t str8, uint64_t mask8) {
    char *end = s + len;
    uint64_t *e64 = (uint64_t *)(uintptr_t)end;
    uint64_t ee = *e64;
    *e64 = str8;
    for (char *p = s;; p++) {
        uint64_t *p64 = (uint64_t *)(uintptr_t)p;
        if ((*p64 & mask8) == str8) {
            *e64 = ee;
            if (p < end)
                return p;
            else
                return NULL;
        }
    }
}

char *mystrstr8_len8(char *s, size_t len, uint64_t str8) {
    char *end = s + len;
    uint64_t *e64 = (uint64_t *)(uintptr_t)end;
    uint64_t ee = *e64;
    *e64 = str8;
    for (char *p = s;; p++) {
        uint64_t *p64 = (uint64_t *)(uintptr_t)p;
        if (*p64 == str8) {
            *e64 = ee;
            if (p < end)
                return p;
            else
                return NULL;
        }
    }
}

int benchmark(int len, const char *needle, char *a) {
    char buf[9] = { 0 };
    strncat(buf, needle, 8);
    int needle_len = strlen(buf);
    uint64_t mask8 = needle_len ? 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF >> (64 - needle_len * 8) : 0;
    uint64_t str8;
    memcpy(&str8, buf, 8);
    memset(a, 'x', len);
    a[len] = '\0';
    int pos = len - needle_len;
    if (pos >= 0 && pos <= len - needle_len)
        memcpy(a + pos, needle, needle_len);

    clock_t c;
    long c1, c2, c3;
    long b1 = 1000000, b2 = 1000000, b3 = 1000000;
    long n1 = 0, n2 = 0, n3 = 0;
    int rep = 100000 / len;
    rep += rep == 0;
    int res = 0;
    void *p1[rep], *p2[rep], *p3[rep];
    while (n1 < 10000) {
        c = clock();
        for (int i = 0; i < rep; i++)
            p1[i] = strstr(a, needle);
        c1 = clock() - c;
        if (needle_len == 8) {
            c = clock();
            for (int i = 0; i < rep; i++)
                p2[i] = mystrstr8_8(a, str8);
            c2 = clock() - c;
            c = clock();
            for (int i = 0; i < rep; i++)
                p3[i] = mystrstr8_len8(a, len, str8);
            c3 = clock() - c;
        } else {
            c = clock();
            for (int i = 0; i < rep; i++)
                p2[i] = mystrstr8(a, str8, mask8);
            c2 = clock() - c;
            c = clock();
            for (int i = 0; i < rep; i++)
                p3[i] = mystrstr8_len(a, len, str8, mask8);
            c3 = clock() - c;
        }
        n1 += c1;
        n2 += c2;
        n3 += c3;
        b1 -= (b1 - c1) * (b1 > c1);
        b2 -= (b2 - c2) * (b2 > c2);
        b3 -= (b3 - c3) * (b3 > c3);
        res = (p1[rep - 1] != p2[rep - 1] || p1[rep - 1] != p3[rep - 1]);
    }
    if (p2[0] != p1[0]) {
        printf("bench(%d, '%s'): mystrstr8 failure: %p, expected %p\n",
               len, needle, p2[0], p1[0]);
    }
    if (p3[0] != p1[0]) {
        printf("bench(%d, '%s'): mystrstr8_len failure: %p, expected %p\n",
               len, needle, p3[0], p1[0]);
    }
    if (res == 0) {
        printf("%-8d %-8s %13.3f %13.3f %13.3f\n", len, needle,
               (double)b1 / rep, (double)b2 / rep, (double)b3 / rep);
    }
    return res;
}

#define MAX_LEN 1000000

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *a = malloc(MAX_LEN + 8);

    // ensure full output is buffered
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOFBF, 16384);

    printf("%-8s %-8s %13s %13s %13s\n",
           "len", "needle", "strstr", "mystrstr8", "mystrstr8_len");

    for (int len = 10; len <= MAX_LEN; len *= 10) {
        benchmark(len, "a", a);
        benchmark(len, "ab", a);
        benchmark(len, "abc", a);
        benchmark(len, "abcd", a);
        benchmark(len, "abcde", a);
        benchmark(len, "abcdef", a);
        benchmark(len, "abcdefg", a);
        benchmark(len, "abcdefgh", a);
    }
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the results on my 2015 Mac x86_64 laptop:

```
len      needle          strstr     mystrstr8 mystrstr8_len
10       a                0.013         0.005         0.008
10       ab               0.013         0.005         0.008
10       abc              0.014         0.005         0.008
10       abcd             0.013         0.004         0.007
10       abcde            0.013         0.004         0.007
10       abcdef           0.013         0.003         0.007
10       abcdefg          0.012         0.003         0.007
10       abcdefgh         0.012         0.002         0.002
100      a                0.076         0.057         0.046
100      ab               0.076         0.056         0.045
100      abc              0.077         0.056         0.045
100      abcd             0.076         0.055         0.044
100      abcde            0.077         0.055         0.044
100      abcdef           0.076         0.054         0.044
100      abcdefg          0.076         0.054         0.043
100      abcdefgh         0.076         0.045         0.040
1000     a                0.610         0.480         0.410
1000     ab               0.610         0.470         0.410
1000     abc              0.610         0.480         0.410
1000     abcd             0.610         0.480         0.410
1000     abcde            0.610         0.470         0.400
1000     abcdef           0.610         0.470         0.410
1000     abcdefg          0.610         0.470         0.400
1000     abcdefgh         0.610         0.400         0.370
10000    a                5.900         4.800         4.100
10000    ab               5.900         4.800         4.100
10000    abc              5.900         4.800         4.100
10000    abcd             5.900         4.800         4.100
10000    abcde            5.900         4.800         4.100
10000    abcdef           5.900         4.800         4.100
10000    abcdefg          5.900         4.800         4.100
10000    abcdefgh         5.900         4.000         3.800
100000   a               59.000        50.000        41.000
100000   ab              59.000        49.000        41.000
100000   abc             59.000        49.000        41.000
100000   abcd            59.000        49.000        41.000
100000   abcde           59.000        49.000        41.000
100000   abcdef          59.000        49.000        41.000
100000   abcdefg         59.000        50.000        41.000
100000   abcdefgh        59.000        40.000        39.000
1000000  a              593.000       493.000       415.000
1000000  ab             589.000       472.000       415.000
1000000  abc            592.000       496.000       413.000
1000000  abcd           590.000       496.000       416.000
1000000  abcde          589.000       495.000       415.000
1000000  abcdef         589.000       495.000       416.000
1000000  abcdefg        589.000       495.000       417.000
1000000  abcdefgh       589.000       406.000       385.000
```

This hack consistently improves performance by 15 to 30% on long strings and even more on shorter ones. I made a special case of 8 byte needles that could be adapted for 1, 2 and 4 byte needles too.

Comment: So many issues.

Comment: @SimonGoater: of course the code has issues, for one thing it only works if the target allows unaligned 64 bit accesses, which is the case for x86_64 targets. The intermediary casts as `(uintptr_t)` silence the compiler warning about the alignment problems. What other issues are you referring to?

Comment: Alignment yes, but strict aliasing violations also, missing bracket, modifying constants, no performance comparison with strstr().

Comment: @SimonGoater: I fixed the typos and included a benchmark.  This approach does improve performance over my standard library's `strstr()` function.  The strict aliasing violations are a potential issue, which I am not sure how to address effectively (aside from the `-fno-strict-aliasing` compiler flag)

Answer (score 1):

If the needle searched starts with a byte value that is rare in the haystack, a simplistic implementation will beat more complicated alternatives:

```
char *mystrstr_naive(const char *s, const char *needle) {
    char *p = (char *)(uintptr_t)s;
    int c = *needle++;
    if (c == '\0')
        return p;
    if (*needle == '\0')
        return strchr(p, c);
    size_t len = strlen(needle);
    while ((p = strchr(p, c)) != NULL) {
        p++;
        if (!memcmp(p, needle, len))
            return p - 1;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

And even faster if the string length is known:

```
char *mystrstr_naive_len(const char *s, size_t slen, const char *needle) {
    char *p = (char *)(uintptr_t)s;
    int c = *needle++;
    if (c == '\0')
        return p;
    if (*needle == '\0')
        return memchr(p, c, slen);
    size_t len = strlen(needle);
    if (len < slen) {
        char *e = p + slen - len;
        while ((p = memchr(p, c, e - p)) != NULL) {
            p++;
            if (!memcmp(p, needle, len))
                return p - 1;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

On my system, if the needle searched starts with a byte value that is rare in the haystack, this is 10 to 20 times faster than `strstr` and the alternatives presented in my other answer.

To improve performance on specific data, you must study the data carefully. The needle being known in advance is a interesting clue, but some other characteristics might be more fruitful.

Comment: I think you can remove the (char *)(uintptr_t) and with it the aliasing issue. Simple solutions are great, especially if they work better.

Comment: @SimonGoater: how is this an aliasing issue? these casts just remove the pointer constness. `char *p; memcpy(&p, &s, sizeof(p));` is an ugly alternative.

Comment: To benefit from looking for a rare character that doesn't have to be at the tip of the needle.

Comment: (As it occurs twice: `if (!memcmp(p+1, needle, len))  return p;` pleases me better than advancing p.)

Comment: @chqrlie Casting a char* to an uintptr is UB. The other way round is okay though.

Comment: I tested your second function and found strstr to be typically ten times faster. Are you sure you're not benchmarking pre-computed resulted from the compiler's optimiser? You should test with strings not known at compile time.

Comment: @SimonGoater: these simplistic functions are only faster *if the needle searched starts with a byte value that is rare in the haystack*.  In this case, the bottleneck is `strchr` or `memchr`. For the general case, they may be much slower than stock `strstr()`.  This answer only pertains to the special case where the needle starts with a rare character. It may fit the OP or not depending on their use case.  They want to squeeze performance for a particular case, analysing the data is the key to finding a tailored solution.

Comment: @greybeard: indeed further data analysis may show that a different character is better suited for a fast scan.

Comment: I've tested `mystrstr_naive_len` with my data. Plus I've hardcoded `const char *needle = "my_needle";` to allow the compiler to optimize `memcmp` (I can easily compile the code at startup and load a shared object, so that's fine for my use-case). As @chqrlie already mentioned, the function is only faster if the first character is rare. Unfortunately, this is not always true for my cases. But maybe I'll decide at startup (=when the first few records are processed) if the first character is rare and then use this function.